# XML/JSON processing

Tags: xml, json, dom, jaxb, jackson

I am writing a set of REST APIs to XML and JSON content type for my application. I would like to make an informed choice of XML/JSON processing libraries while designing and implementing these APIs. Following are various non-functional requirements for APIs:

1. Performance - The APIs deal with huge amount of data (payload can be in Megabytes). The API input size is less compared to API output.
2. Filtering capability - The caller of the API should be able to specify filter criteria based on which the output is trimmed to optimize bandwidth consumption.

As part of our research and analysis we did take a look at DOM APIs and JAXB/Jackson APIs. Request your advice/suggestion on choosing the correct APIs considering the non-functional requirements listed above.

This is my understanding of marshalling & un-marshalling process using these APIs. Please correct me if I am wrong.

- DOM APIs - 2 step process (using DOM parser & XMLSerializer)
  XML/JSON to DOM to POJO & POJO to DOM to XML/JSON
- JAXB APIs - single step process (using annotations)
  XML/JSON to POJO & POJO to XML/JSON

Though JAXB annotations are easier and more convenient, in terms of marshalling/unmarshalling does DOM APIs perform better?

Also, is there any guidelines on when to choose what XML processing library?
For multiple content type handling, is it better to choose a different libraries. For eg. Jackson for JSON and JAXB for XML (purely for performance).

For JSON content type, is there any overhead in transforming JSON to and from DOM object?

Comment: In short, go for StAX (supported in JAXB/Jackson). DOM is not suitable for big XMLs so you need event-based which is SAX or StAX and StAX is easier to handle. Jackson, Woodstox is a way to go.

Comment: Thanks. Appreciate your help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, couple of points:

1. Yes, converting between JSON and DOM (XML) has not only significant (and, generally, unnecessary) overhead. Worse, it is often lossy, due to different information model JSON and XML have. In my opinion, this option (Jettison et al) should be avoided.
2. For JAXB style operation, there is also Jackson XML module (https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml/), which can be convenient when supporting both XML and JSON
3. DOM is slower approach partly due to 2-phase processing, and partly because memory usage is 3-5x higher than with direct data-binding (depending on kind of data)

Some benefits of DOM-based approach are:

1. It is XML specific, so if specific XML aspects or tooling matter (use of XPath, XML Schema) it is possible to access all details of XML usage
2. Since DOM is untyped, flexible, it is sometimes better fit for dynamic and loosely (... or, badly...) structured data.

but I would agree with @lexicore in that DOM should be last choice if other approaches do not work. Especially when dealing with large data.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. This is definitely helpful